# Passenger > 5.0.15, jRuby 9.0.5.0 and passenger_spawn_method

Tags: ruby, passenger, jruby, rack, puma

I try to use passenger standalone 5.0.26 with RACK app on jRuby 9.0.5.0. Is only direct passenger_spawn_method possible?

Passenger 5.0.26 with smart spawning and MRI 2.3.0 is 1.5 times faster than with direct spawning and jRuby 9. Same passenger + mri 2.3.0 is 3 times faster than Puma + jRuby on same RACK app. What the point to use puma + jruby, when passenger + mri is so much faster?